# Problems including the SDL.h file

Tags: c++, makefile, sdl

I'm trying to run a simple code that includes the "SDL.h" file, just to verify it works properly and it gives me no errors, but it's not like that. I'm using VS Code and MinGW compiler. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL.h>

int main (int arcg, char* arcv[]) {
    std::cout << "it works";
    return 0;
}
```

I've installed all the SDL2 stuff and I put all the headers i need in a "sdl" folder, and this is my makefile:

```
all:
g++ -Iinclude -Iinclude/sdl -Iinclude/headers -Llib -o Main src/*.cpp -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image
```

The inconsistency is that while I'm writing the code the compiler doesn't give me errors (in other similar situations it does (the red underline), for example if I try to include a .h that doesn't exist) and when i digit "#include" it shows me all the files that i can include from the "sdl" folder, but when i run the program the error occurs:

```
main.cpp:2:10: fatal error: SDL.h: No such file or directory
2 | #include <SDL.h>
  |          ^~~~~~~
```

Someone help me

This is the directory structure pointed by tree:

```
.
├── Main.exe
├── MakeFile
├── SDL2.dll
├── SDL2_image.dll
├── include
│   ├── headers
│   └── sdl
│       ├── SDL.exe
│       ├── SDL.h
│       ├── SDL_assert.h
│       ├── SDL_atomic.h
│       ├── SDL_audio.h
│       ├── SDL_bits.h
│       ├── SDL_blendmode.h
│       ├── SDL_clipboard.h
│       ├── SDL_config.h
│       ├── SDL_cpuinfo.h
│       ├── SDL_egl.h
│       ├── SDL_endian.h
│       ├── SDL_error.h
│       ├── SDL_events.h
│       ├── SDL_filesystem.h
│       ├── SDL_gamecontroller.h
│       ├── SDL_gesture.h
│       ├── SDL_haptic.h
│       ├── SDL_hidapi.h
│       ├── SDL_hints.h
│       ├── SDL_image.h
│       ├── SDL_joystick.h
│       ├── SDL_keyboard.h
│       ├── SDL_keycode.h
│       ├── SDL_loadso.h
│       ├── SDL_locale.h
│       ├── SDL_log.h
│       ├── SDL_main.h
│       ├── SDL_messagebox.h
│       ├── SDL_metal.h
│       ├── SDL_misc.h
│       ├── SDL_mouse.h
│       ├── SDL_mutex.h
│       ├── SDL_name.h
│       ├── SDL_opengl.h
│       ├── SDL_opengl_glext.h
│       ├── SDL_opengles.h
│       ├── SDL_opengles2.h
│       ├── SDL_opengles2_gl2.h
│       ├── SDL_opengles2_gl2ext.h
│       ├── SDL_opengles2_gl2platform.h
│       ├── SDL_opengles2_khrplatform.h
│       ├── SDL_pixels.h
│       ├── SDL_platform.h
│       ├── SDL_power.h
│       ├── SDL_quit.h
│       ├── SDL_rect.h
│       ├── SDL_render.h
│       ├── SDL_revision.h
│       ├── SDL_rwops.h
│       ├── SDL_scancode.h
│       ├── SDL_sensor.h
│       ├── SDL_shape.h
│       ├── SDL_stdinc.h
│       ├── SDL_surface.h
│       ├── SDL_system.h
│       ├── SDL_syswm.h
│       ├── SDL_test.h
│       ├── SDL_test_assert.h
│       ├── SDL_test_common.h
│       ├── SDL_test_compare.h
│       ├── SDL_test_crc32.h
│       ├── SDL_test_font.h
│       ├── SDL_test_fuzzer.h
│       ├── SDL_test_harness.h
│       ├── SDL_test_images.h
│       ├── SDL_test_log.h
│       ├── SDL_test_md5.h
│       ├── SDL_test_memory.h
│       ├── SDL_test_random.h
│       ├── SDL_thread.h
│       ├── SDL_timer.h
│       ├── SDL_touch.h
│       ├── SDL_types.h
│       ├── SDL_version.h
│       ├── SDL_video.h
│       ├── SDL_vulkan.h
│       ├── begin_code.h
│       └── close_code.h
├── lib
│   ├── cmake
│   │   └── SDL2
│   │       ├── sdl2-config-version.cmake
│   │       └── sdl2-config.cmake
│   ├── libSDL2.a
│   ├── libSDL2.dll.a
│   ├── libSDL2.la
│   ├── libSDL2_image.a
│   ├── libSDL2_image.dll.a
│   ├── libSDL2_image.la
│   ├── libSDL2_test.a
│   ├── libSDL2_test.la
│   ├── libSDL2main.a
│   ├── libSDL2main.la
│   └── pkgconfig
│       ├── SDL2_image.pc
│       └── sdl2.pc
├── libjpeg-9.dll
├── libpng16-16.dll
├── libtiff-5.dll
├── libwebp-7.dll
├── src
│   └── main.cpp
└── zlib1.dll

8 directories, 103 files
```

And this is the new makefile:

```
all:
    g++ -Iinclude -Iinclude/sdl -Iinclude/headers -Llib -o Main src/*.cpp -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image 
    tree .
```

Comment: The compiler command looks ok. Can you confirm that you have `SDL.h` in one of the directories passed to `-I`? Not in subdirectories.

Comment: Since `SDL.h` is shipped in a directory called `SDL2`, I'd expect one of the paths passed to `-I` to end with `SDL2`.

Comment: thank you for the asnwer, I have SDL.h in the subdirectory "sdl" (which is in the directory "include") but i passed include/sdl

Comment: It should work then. You're not telling us something.

Comment: I really don't know

Comment: It may be a lot simpler for you if you switch to use msys2 and have it install SDL2 properly using its package manager. Then you don't need to set the path since it will be in the system paths that your compiler already searches. https://www.msys2.org/

Comment: @drescherjm thank you, i will try. But I have to understand why it does so.

Comment: It could help us if you show the lines above: `main.cpp:2:10: fatal error: SDL.h: No such file or directory` so we can see the exact build command used.

Comment: ***the compiler doesn't give me errors (in other similar situations it does (the red underline)*** Red underlines are independent from your build task. Intellisense and building are handled and configured separately.

Comment: Can you show the contents of `include/sdl` to us?

Comment: @drescherjm these are the lines above:       [Running] cd "c:\Users\giordano\Desktop\project\src\" && g++ main.cpp -o main && "c:\Users\giordano\Desktop\project\src\"main

Comment: @HolyBlackCat i don't know how to show you the contents

Comment: Figure something out. You could at least list the filenames inside.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat begin_code
close_code
SDL
SDL_assert
SDL_atomic
SDL_audio
SDL_bits
SDL_blendmode
SDL_clipboard
SDL_config
SDL_cpuinfo
SDL_egl
SDL_endian
SDL_error
SDL_events
SDL_filesystem
SDL_gamecontroller
SDL_gesture
SDL_haptic
SDL_hidapi
SDL_hints
SDL_image
SDL_joystick
SDL_keyboard
SDL_keycode
SDL_loadso
SDL_locale
SDL_log
SDL_main
SDL_messagebox
SDL_metal
SDL_misc
SDL_mouse
SDL_mutex
SDL_name
SDL_opengl
SDL_opengl_glext
SDL_opengles
SDL_opengles2
SDL_opengles2_gl2
SDL_opengles2_gl2ext
SDL_opengles2_gl2platform
SDL_opengles2_khrplatform

Comment: SDL_pixels
SDL_platform
SDL_power
SDL_quit
SDL_rect
SDL_render
SDL_revision
SDL_rwops
SDL_scancode
SDL_sensor
SDL_shape
SDL_stdinc
SDL_surface
SDL_system
SDL_syswm
SDL_test
SDL_test_assert
SDL_test_common
SDL_test_compare
SDL_test_crc32
SDL_test_font
SDL_test_fuzzer
SDL_test_harness
SDL_test_images
SDL_test_log
SDL_test_md5
SDL_test_memory
SDL_test_random
SDL_thread
SDL_timer
SDL_touch
SDL_types
SDL_version
SDL_video
SDL_vulkan

Comment: Hmm, this looks ok. You're making some simple mistake - either this is not the actual compiler command you're using, or you're running it from a wrong directory, or something else. Here's what I suggest: [install MSYS2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30069830/2752075), from it install the compiler, `make` and `tree`, add `tree .` next to the compiler command to print the directory contents, and run the makefile again (from MSYS2 shell this time). Then show what `tree` prints.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat okay thank you, I will try tomorrow

Comment: When you try tomorrow my advice is to put the additional information in your question. It's difficult to read it in the comments.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I'm sorry I'm late, i've installed MSYS2, the compiler, make and tree, but I don't know how to do the rest (adding tree . next to the compiler command and running the makefile), how can I do it?

Comment: Below the `g++ ...` line in the makefile, add `tree .`. Note that those two lines have to have a single 'tab' at the left. Then run the makefile as usual and show the directory structure printed by `tree`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat okay I did it editing the question above

Comment: There's something you're not telling us, it should work. Can you show the new makefile? How exactly do you run it? Was the `tree` output produced by running the makefile with the `tree .` command in it, or by you manually calling `tree`?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Added above

Comment: The `cd "...\src" && g++ main.cpp -o main` suggests it's not the `make all` command you've shown actually being run.